# How rational can help in mainframe development

Tags: zos, ibm-rational

Can someone tell me,
         How Rational suite can help the mainframe z/os development process, testing and deployments and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  IBM will be happy to promote their [Rational](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/) software.

Edited based on the comment: Rational software on the workstation has secret proprietary hooks into an IBM mainframe (JES, file structure) that no other software can have.

Comment: I know...just a brief idea will be helpful.